# I need the query to only show count(sku) > 10

Tags: where-clause, sqlanywhere, where-in

How can I add up the totals from a column I've already asked to sum up?

```
select 
--distinct  batch_date, bol_nbr, cur_opr, lane_nbr, size_code, sku 
loc_code, ship_lab, size_code, sku, COUNT(SKU)
from sherwin.prdinv
where sku IN ('B28W8030', 'B20W12651', 'A87W1351', 'B31W4651', 'A6W151') and (loc_code like 'H0%' or (loc_code like 'B%' ))
and REGEXP_LIKE((SUBSTR(loc_code,3)), '^[[:digit:]]+$')
group by loc_code, ship_lab, SKU, size_code
ORDER BY Loc_code asc;
```

I tried: `where sku IN ('B28W8030', 'B20W12651', 'A87W1351', 'B31W4651', 'A6W151') and (loc_code like 'H0%' or (loc_code like 'B%' ) and (count(sku) > 10)`

I wanted the report to only show me sku's where the value was greater than 10

Comment: Do you want to sum the count?

Comment: No just to only show quantities of the COUNT of sku that are below 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just add the `HAVING` clause to your query.

```
select distinct  batch_date, bol_nbr, cur_opr, lane_nbr, size_code, sku 
loc_code, ship_lab, size_code, sku, COUNT(SKU)
from sherwin.prdinv
where sku IN ('B28W8030', 'B20W12651', 'A87W1351', 'B31W4651', 'A6W151') and (loc_code like 'H0%' or (loc_code like 'B%' ))
and REGEXP_LIKE((SUBSTR(loc_code,3)), '^[[:digit:]]+$')
group by loc_code, ship_lab, SKU, size_code
having COUNT(SKU) < 10
ORDER BY Loc_code asc;
```